# Multiplying ndarray with scalar: TypeError: invalid type promotion

Tags: python, numpy, genfromtxt, structured-array

I'm trying to multiply every column in an ndarray by a scalar. When I try to do this, I get the error `TypeError: invalid type promotion`.

I've tried using `array.astype(float)`, but this gives all `NaN`s.

```
array = np.genfromtxt("file.csv", dtype=float, delimiter='\t', names=True)

newarray = array*4.0
```

`file.csv` has a number of column headers. For example:

```
array['col_a'] = [5.0, 6.0]
```

After multiplying by the scalar, I want: 
`newarray['col_a']` to be `[20.0, 24.0]`

Comment: You have to multiply each field separately.  Or omit the `names` parameter and get a 2d array of dtype float.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm honestly amazed that this has never come up in my own code, but it turns out that Numpy structured arrays (ie arrays with field names) [don't support the standard arithmetic operators](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.15.0/user/basics.rec.html#structure-comparison) `+`, `-`, `*`, or `/` (see footnote *).

Thus, your only option is to work with a non-structured version of your array. @hpaulj's comment points out the ways you can do so ([this old answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50942539/425458) contains a thorough exploration of exactly how you can get addition to work with structured arrays.). Either index a single field (the result of which behaves like a standard array) and multiply that:

```
import numpy as np
from io import StringIO

csv = '''col_a\tcol_b\tcol_c
5.0\t19.6\t22.8
6.0\t42.42\t39.208
'''

arr = np.genfromtxt(StringIO(csv), dtype=np.float64, delimiter='\t', names=True)

xcol_a = arr['col_a']*4
print(xcol_a)
# output: [20. 24.]
```

or omit the `names=True` kwarg when you generate your array (which makes `np.genfromtxt` return a standard array instead of a structured one):

```
arrstd = np.genfromtxt(StringIO(csv), dtype=np.float64, delimiter='\t', skip_header=True)

print(arrstd*4)
# output: [[ 20.     78.4    91.2  ]
#          [ 24.    169.68  156.832]]
```

*: Technically, it appears that many of Numpy's built-in [`ufunc`'s](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.15.1/reference/ufuncs.html) are not supported when working with structured arrays. At least some of the comparison functions/operators (`<`, `>`, and `==`) [are supported](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.15.0/user/basics.rec.html#viewing-structured-arrays-containing-objects).

Comment: Just in case any one else has this problem, I used genfromtext to get the names for each column, used tips from above to do the multiplication, and then used [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10742406/programmatically-add-column-names-to-numpy-ndarray?rq=1) to add back the column names.