# element wise sum of structured arrays in numpy

Tags: python, numpy, numpy-ndarray, numpy-ufunc

I wonder if it is possible at all to perform element-wise sum (or other operations) of two structured numpy arrays of an identical shape.

```
arr1 = np.array([[1,2,3],[2,3,4]], dtype=[("x", "f8"),("y", "f8")])
arr2 = np.array([[5,4,3],[9,6,4]], dtype=[("x", "f8"),("y", "f8")])
arr3 = np.sum(arr1, arr2)
```

says "ufunc 'add' did not contain a loop with signature matching types dtype([('x', '

If it is not possible, it will be great to understand why that is impossible or impractical to implement in numpy.

Comment: Have to do the sum, or other math field by field. In general fields may include strings and/or other dtypes that don't implement math.

Comment: if the dtype is uniform... arr.view((arr.dtype[0], len(arr.dtype.names))).sum(axis=0) … but separate it out into components so you can see what is going on

Comment: @hpaulj That's very true. I never store strings in ndarrays, so I overlooked that simple fact...! If you want, I will take it as the answer. It may look too short, but your comment clearly solved the problem :)

Comment: This works for you? `arr.view(np.float32).reshape(arr.shape + (-1,))` I think it is similar to @NaN solution

Comment: @NaN  - I think my example was confusing. I've updated the example. Your previous suggestion is only applicable to a single array and shrinks the array along an axis. So, I'm afraid they don't work.

Comment: @JonnyCrunch  - I've updated the example. Like NaN's suggestion, your previous suggestion is only applicable to a single array and it duplicates the array. I must have confused you.

Comment: related : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50931421/numpy-structured-array-fails-basic-numpy-operations

Comment: Normally structured arrays are initialized with list(s) of tuples.   Since you don't have tuples it creates a (2,2) array with the `x` and `y` values repeated.  @JonnyCrunch s point is that in some cases a structured array can be `viewed` as a uniform simple dtype, but you have to watch the shape.

Comment: Expanding on the `view` idea, it is possible to define a `dtype` with overlapping fields.  In this case a dtype that defines both `x` and `y`, and an `xy` field that occupies the same slots.  IN that case you could do math on `arr['xy']` and see the results in the `x`,`y` fields.  But we'd have to study the `dtype` documentation to do that right.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

With your array:

```
In [236]: arr1 = np.array([[1,2,3],[2,3,4]], dtype=[("x", "f8"),("y", "f8")])
In [237]: arr1
Out[237]: 
array([[(1., 1.), (2., 2.), (3., 3.)],
       [(2., 2.), (3., 3.), (4., 4.)]], dtype=[('x', '<f8'), ('y', '<f8')])
In [238]: arr1['x']
Out[238]: 
array([[1., 2., 3.],
       [2., 3., 4.]])
```

Normally the data for a structured array is provided in the form a list(s) of tuples., same as displayed in `Out[237]`.  Without the tuples `np.array` assigns the same value to both fields.

You have to do math on each field separately:

```
In [239]: arr1['y'] *= 10
In [240]: arr1
Out[240]: 
array([[(1., 10.), (2., 20.), (3., 30.)],
       [(2., 20.), (3., 30.), (4., 40.)]],
      dtype=[('x', '<f8'), ('y', '<f8')])
```

Math operations are defined for simple dtypes like `int` and `float`, and uses compiled code where possible.

This error means that the `add` `ufunc` has not been defined for this compound dtype.  And I think that's true for all compound dtypes.

```
In [242]: arr1 + arr1
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-242-345397c600ce> in <module>()
----> 1 arr1 + arr1

TypeError: ufunc 'add' did not contain a loop with signature matching types dtype([('x', '<f8'), ('y', '<f8')]) dtype([('x', '<f8'), ('y', '<f8')]) dtype([('x', '<f8'), ('y', '<f8')])
```

Since the fields in this case have the same base dtype, we can define another compound dtype that can 'view' it:

```
In [243]: dt2 = np.dtype([('xy', 'f8', 2)])
In [244]: arr2 = arr1.view(dt2)
In [245]: arr2
Out[245]: 
array([[([ 1., 10.],), ([ 2., 20.],), ([ 3., 30.],)],
       [([ 2., 20.],), ([ 3., 30.],), ([ 4., 40.],)]],
      dtype=[('xy', '<f8', (2,))])
In [246]: arr2['xy']
Out[246]: 
array([[[ 1., 10.],
        [ 2., 20.],
        [ 3., 30.]],

       [[ 2., 20.],
        [ 3., 30.],
        [ 4., 40.]]])
```

Math on that field will be seen in the original array:

```
In [247]: arr2['xy'] += .1
In [248]: arr2
Out[248]: 
array([[([ 1.1, 10.1],), ([ 2.1, 20.1],), ([ 3.1, 30.1],)],
       [([ 2.1, 20.1],), ([ 3.1, 30.1],), ([ 4.1, 40.1],)]],
      dtype=[('xy', '<f8', (2,))])
In [249]: arr1
Out[249]: 
array([[(1.1, 10.1), (2.1, 20.1), (3.1, 30.1)],
       [(2.1, 20.1), (3.1, 30.1), (4.1, 40.1)]],
      dtype=[('x', '<f8'), ('y', '<f8')])
```

We can also `view` it as a simple dtype, but will have to adjust the shape:

```
In [250]: arr3 = arr1.view('f8')
In [251]: arr3
Out[251]: 
array([[ 1.1, 10.1,  2.1, 20.1,  3.1, 30.1],
       [ 2.1, 20.1,  3.1, 30.1,  4.1, 40.1]])
In [252]: arr3.reshape(2,3,2)
Out[252]: 
array([[[ 1.1, 10.1],
        [ 2.1, 20.1],
        [ 3.1, 30.1]],

       [[ 2.1, 20.1],
        [ 3.1, 30.1],
        [ 4.1, 40.1]]])
```

Comment: I like the trick using a view to get a "pure" number array! I think this is overkill to the present problem, but will be useful at some point.