# How to get a sum of a structured numpy array?

Tags: python, numpy

I am trying to get the sum of a structured array.  Do a need a "for" loop around the field names, or can I do it in one line.  I do this about a million times per run, so I need to keep it quick.

```
>>> test = np.array([(1,2,3),(4,5,6)], dtype={'names' : ["One", "Two", "Three"], 'formats' : ["f8"]*3})
>>> test
array([(1., 2., 3.), (4., 5., 6.)],
      dtype=[('One', '<f8'), ('Two', '<f8'), ('Three', '<f8')])
>>> np.sum(test)
...
numpy.core._exceptions._UFuncNoLoopError: ufunc 'add' did not contain a loop with signature matching types (dtype([('One', '<f8'), ('Two', '<f8'), ('Three', '<f8')]), dtype([('One', '<f8'), ('Two', '<f8'), ('Three', '<f8')])) -> None
```

similar for np.sum(test, axis=0)

I was expecting a structured array: [(5, 7, 9), dtype=...].  At least, no errors.

Comment: You could use view(): https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54517950/element-wise-sum-of-structured-arrays-in-numpy However, note that this is not type safe.

Comment: As long as the number fields is relatively small (conpared to the number of records), there's little harm in iterating on them.  You could also also explore using `numpy.lib.recfunctions.structured_to_unstructured` to get a 2d array.  Many of the `recfunctions` iterate on fields.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, in this case, since your structure has the same primitive types, you can use a view easily enough:

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> test = np.array([(1,2,3),(4,5,6)], dtype={'names' : ["One", "Two", "Three"], 'formats' : ["f8"]*3})
>>> test.view('f8').reshape(-1,3).sum(axis=0)
array([5., 7., 9.])
```

Now, if you couldn't easily create a view from your original structured dtype, you could use a loop over the fields, which shouldn't be terribly slow:

```
>>> result = np.zeros_like(test, shape=(1,))
>>> for field in test.dtype.fields:
...     result[field] = test[field].sum()
...
>>> result
array([(5., 7., 9.)],
      dtype=[('One', '<f8'), ('Two', '<f8'), ('Three', '<f8')])
```

Comment: That's it, thanks.  I use scipy.minimize, so outside of the function, I can use the for loop.  Inside, I'll use view.